# Textbox not getting readonly

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a textbox, on click, it allows you to select date from calendar control. If the date is deleted, it should uncheck the checkbox available just next to the textbox.

With below code, I am able to achieve everything other than making the textbox readonly so that user is not able to type anything. Also, once the text is selected, checkbox gets checked but when text is deleted the checkbox doesn't get unchecked.

Can anyone suggest what needs I might be doing wrong here ?

```
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalForDate"  runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDate" Format="MM/dd/yyyy" PopupPosition="BottomLeft" DefaultView="Days"></asp:CalendarExtender>                                    
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDate" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState = "false" onKeyPress="javascript:return ChkCheckBox()" OnTextChanged="txtDate_OnTextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

The javascript code:

```
    function ChkCheckBox() {
                var txtDate = document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl00_cphMSTMainPage_cphMSTLDAHomePage_txtDate').value;    
                if (txtDate.length == 9) {
                    document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl00_cphMSTMainPage_cphMSTLDAHomePage_chkDate').checked = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl00_cphMSTMainPage_cphMSTLDAHomePage_chkDate').checked = false;
                }
```

In pageload I have added:

```
     if (!IsPostBack){     
txtDate.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");}
```

And on text changed:

```
public void txtDate_OnTextChanged(object o, EventArgs e){           
if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDate.Text)))
{                                          
     chkDate.Visible = true;
     chkDate.Checked = true;
 }
else
{
     chkDate.Visible = true;
     chkDate.Checked = false;
}    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using jquery. I am sending you the sample code. Please don't hesitate to ask further assistance if needed.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#txtDate').on('change', function () {
            //console.log('Tested');
            if ($(this).val().toString().trim() != '') {
                $('[Id*=ckTest]').attr('checked', 'checked');
            }
            else {
                $('[Id*=ckTest]').removeAttr('checked');
            }
        });

        $('#btnClear').click(function () {
            $('#txtDate').val('');
            $('#txtDate').trigger('change');
        });
    });
</script>
```

The code file is as below.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="ckTest" runat="server" />
        <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDate" />
        <button id="btnClear">Clear</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Just add jquery to project i used
jquery-2.1.4.min.js

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I don't want to use new things, that is ajaxtoolkit and jQuery. Can you suggest something using Javascript and Asp:CalendarExtender

Comment: Plus my Javascript is also doing similar action but somehow for unchecking it doesn't get triggered.

Comment: Can you send me sample project so that i can code for you. Upload on github and share link over here. I will look into it soon.